# React Login Component on Axios

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

How to make React Login Component via API and Redirect to home while give session (via Jwt)?

I've tried using default Axios function but stuck with the 404 Error, while the API can be reach via GET

Below is Login.js

```
 handleSubmit = input => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    input.preventDefault();

    if (this.formisValid(this.state)) {
      this.setState({ errors: [], loading: true });
      axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http:localhost:3003/api/v1/login',
        data: {
          email    : this.state.email,
          password : this.state.password
        }
      }).then( user => {

        this.setState({ 
          initialState,
          submit: true
        });
        this.setState({ loading: false});
        console.log('User Login', user)

      }).catch((response) => {
        // ? Show to user that request is failed
        this.setState({ errors:[response ]})
        this.setState({ loading: false });
        console.log('request failed', response)
      });
    }
  };
```

Below is the API GET Login result (via browser)

```
{"success":false,"data":{"error":"Body cannot be empty"}}
```

The expected result is User can be directed to home (/) after login success (and have session via Jwt)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3003/api/v1/login', {
      email    : this.state.email,
      password : this.state.password
    })
  .then(user => {
    /* */
  })
```

Comment: Yes, but The 404 Not Found problem still appear mate

Comment: This might be a backend error. Is it working fine from another client (i.e postman)?

Comment: Yes I get the same error via Postman, but can reach via GET Request

Comment: then there is a problem on your server side code, you need to make sure post request is available